# how to autofill the other fields based on another field's value

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

this is my ajax/jquery code which is sending value of phone field to controller

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    debugger;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
        $("#button").click(function () {
            debugger;
            alert("phonechanged");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: '@Url.Action("CheckPhone")',
                //data: { phone: $("#phone").val() },
                data: JSON.stringify({ phone: $("#phone").val() }),
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    $("#firstName").val(obj.firstName);

                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    debugger;
                    alert('Failed to retrieve customer.' + ex);
                }
            });

            return false;
        })
    });
</script>
```

and this is my controller method which is supposed to return the customer, if any, and then have the ajax change the values of field. my code isnot working. I also don't know how to check for null values if no customer has that phone number.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CheckPhone(string phone)
{
    Customer cm = new Customer();
    bool check = false;
    Leads_Management_SystemEntities lmsEntities = new Leads_Management_SystemEntities();
    cm = lmsEntities.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.phoneNum1 == phone || x.phoneNum2 == phone || x.phoneNum3 == phone);


    string value = string.Empty;
    value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cm, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    });

    return Json(value);
}
```

razor code

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.firstName, new { id = "firstName" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.firstName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.email)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.city, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.city)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.city)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.country, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.country)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.country)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.phoneNum1, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.phoneNum1, new { id = "phone" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.phoneNum1)
            </div>
        </div>

            <input type="submit" value="submit" id="button" />


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.phoneNum2, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.phoneNum2)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.phoneNum2)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.phoneNum3, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.phoneNum3)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.phoneNum3)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.propertyOwned, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.propertyOwned)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.propertyOwned)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.address)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CNIC, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CNIC)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CNIC)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lastName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lastName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lastName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.budgetTo, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.budgetTo)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.budgetTo)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.budgetFrom, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.budgetFrom)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.budgetFrom)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.leadScoreId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.leadScoreId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.lsList, "Select leadscore")
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.leadScoreId)*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.leadScoreId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.plotSize, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.plotSize)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.plotSize)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.statusId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.statusId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.statusList, "Select status")
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.statusId)*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.statusId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.uniqueHandle, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.uniqueHandle)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.uniqueHandle)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.plotTypeId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.plotTypeId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ptList, "Select plotType")



                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.plotTypeId)*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.plotTypeId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Block, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Block)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Block)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.commentsDetails, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.commentsDetails)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.commentsDetails)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.typeId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.typeId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.stList, "Select sourcetype")
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.typeId)*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.typeId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sourceTime, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sourceTime)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sourceTime)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.commentsSource, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.commentsSource)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.commentsSource)
            </div>
        </div>
@*this form group wasnot auto generated*@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tags, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.tags, (MultiSelectList)(ViewData["tags"]) as SelectList)
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.tags)*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tags)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.features, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.features, (MultiSelectList)(ViewData["features"]) as SelectList)
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.features)*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.features)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: First of all, are you hitting the controller action? If you put a debug point on "CheckPhone", do you reach it?

Comment: yes its hitting it, but its sending a null value

Comment: Do a view source on the browser to ensure that only one input element has "phone" as id. Also write to console [ console.log($("#phone").val()); ] in before the ajax call to check what value you are reading.

Comment: Also add a "@" before the "id" in your @Html.EditorFor